# mouseleave/enter bind/unbind logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple script for a form. The script will show the form when the user hovers over the container div. Then I want to check to see if the user clicks on any form input, if not the form will hide. If an input or textarea are in focus I unbind mouseleave. If the user want's to close the form at this point he needs to click on a close button.

The problem I have right now is that after I have an input in focus and I close the form, on the next hover the form doesn't hide. I have to click the close button again. How do I 'reset' or disable the mouseleave unbind when the user clicks on close?

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
$(".close").on('click', function() {
    $(".background").removeClass("green");
    $(".q-form").hide();
    $('.close').hide();
});

$(".container-background").on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.q-form').show();
    $('.close').show();
    $('.background').addClass("green");
});

$(".container-background").on('mouseleave', function() {
    f ($('#contactForm input').is(':focus')) {
        $(".container-background").off("mouseleave"); 
            } else { 
                $('.q-form').hide();
                $('.close').hide();
                $('.background').removeClass("green");
            }
});
```

Comment: No need to unbind mouseleave. Just don't do anything on mouseleave if input has focus. Basically... on mouseleave  if form not in focus close the form.

Comment: Well, that was a quick fix, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a little offtopic: I recommend against checking for an `input` in `:focus`. A better approach for the scenario you described is to have:

```
$(document).on("focus", "#contactForm input", function() {
    $(".container-background").off("mouseleave");
});
```

---

As for the problem you have with unbinding the event handler, you can just reattach it on form close:

```
$(".container-background").on("mouseleave", myFunction);
$(".close").on('click', function() {
    $(".background").removeClass("green");
    $(".q-form").hide();
    $('.close').hide();
    $(".container-background").off("mouseleave", myFunction)
                              .on("mouseleave", myFunction);
});
var myFunction = function() {
    // You won't need this condition if you also do what's above
    if (!$('#contactForm input').is(':focus')) {
        $('.q-form').hide();
        $('.close').hide();
        $('.background').removeClass("green");
    }
};
```

On second thought you can also just do this, and not have the `.off()` call at all:

```
if (!$('#contactForm input').is(':focus')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like to use .hover or .on. I use .mouseenter and .mouseleave. Then, if you just create a .mouseenter, there would be no code to put it back into the unfocused state. Here is an example:

> $("#something").mouseenter(function(){
>      $(this).animate({
>          //some css or whatever.
>      })
>   })
>   as long as you don't put a .mouseleave, it should not unfocus.